# How to batch upload by filestack python

Tags: python-3.x

Filestack python has no method for bulk uploading，but filestack js has methods for bulk uploading

Upload images through the thread pool

```
client.upload(filepath=image_url, store_params={'location': 's3', 'path': f"{BUD_WORKSPACE_ID}/{BUD_CORE_ID}/{image_url.split('../')[-1]}"})
list(executor.map(self.send_images, img_paths))
```